How to resolve Schema validation failed in AWS Graphql Schema Transformer v1 to v2
I had an old project which had the following schema:


type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  imageUri: String
  posts: [Post] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type Post @model @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID"]) {
  id: ID!
  videoUri: String!
  description: String!

  userID: ID!
  user: User @connection(fields: ["userID"])

  songID: ID!
  song: Song @connection(fields: ["songID"])
}

type Song @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  imageUri: String
}



But when I tried changing the code or transform the code v2, I started having the error below, when I try using amplify update api:

Schema validation failed.

Unknown argument "fields" on directive "@index".
GraphQL request:13:41
12 |   description: String!
13 |   byUser: [Post] @index(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID"])
|                                         ^
14 |   userID: ID!
Please, what's the right code to resolve the issue?

In Amplify GraphQL Transform v2 has been replaced to more relation directives like (@hasMany, @belongsTo, @hasOne, and @manyToMany), also the field  argument in @index directive is not used in the same way as before.
For User Type, the @connection for posts will be replaced with @hasMany. 
For the previous @connection needs to be changed to @belongsTo for linking to User and Song.
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!
  imageUri: String
  posts: [Post] @hasMany(indexName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type Post @model @index(name: "byUser", sortKeyFields: ["userID"]) {
  id: ID!
  videoUri: String!
  description: String!
  
  userID: ID!
  user: User @belongsTo(fields: ["userID"])

  songID: ID!
  song: Song @belongsTo(fields: ["songID"])
}

type Song @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  imageUri: String
}

Here The @index directive is used to create an index which is needed for the @hasMany relationship.

Hi Mina, thanks so much for your response. When I ran the code, I still get this error: Directive "@index" may not be used on OBJECT.
